# Passing compressed xml from response to request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, post-processor

I have an export service which returns a compressed xml, and I save it in a zip file. An import service receives the content of the file and changes the database accordingly.

I am trying to write a simple test suite in JMeter (export and then import) and I got stuck at the following: how to take the compressed xml from the response of the export service and to pass it in the request of the import service? Is this possible in JMeter? I googled it, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways of doing this:

1. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) PostProcessor. If you not too familiar with regex, the following one will return the whole response body

   ```
   (?s)(^.*)
   ```
2. Using [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor). Only one line of code is required to store the whole response into "response" JMeter Variable.

   ```
   vars.put("response", new String(data));
   ```
3. It is possible to store response into a file via [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener from the export service and passing the file to the import service. See [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide for details on how to properly do this as there are some nuances.